Force widget rebuild while desktop Flutter app is hidden
I have created a Flutter app, which:

Reads network events and updates the UI accordingly.
I run on macOS and screen-capture with OBS (although I suspect the problem will happen in Windows too).

Unfortunately, the app doesn't refresh while hidden (i.e. while the app's window is completely covered with something else). This means that the OBS feed doesn't update properly when the app's Window is fully covered by other windows.
I would like to know how can I enforce the app to refresh the UI, even when hidden.
Here is a modified version of the Flutter Test application showcasing the problem.
It increments the counter periodically in the background (simulating the network updates) and prints:

Whenever the counter is incremented
whenever the main widget's build() method is called
whenever the application lifecycle state changes

I executed the app, hid it's window with other windows and undid it again. Here's the output:
flutter: rebuilding widget
flutter: incrementing counter
flutter: rebuilding widget
flutter: incrementing counter
flutter: rebuilding widget
flutter: incrementing counter
flutter: rebuilding widget
flutter: lifecycle changed to AppLifecycleState.hidden
flutter: incrementing counter
flutter: incrementing counter
flutter: incrementing counter
flutter: lifecycle changed to AppLifecycleState.inactive
flutter: rebuilding widget
flutter: incrementing counter
flutter: rebuilding widget
flutter: incrementing counter
flutter: rebuilding widget
flutter: incrementing counter
flutter: rebuilding widget
flutter: lifecycle changed to AppLifecycleState.resumed
flutter: incrementing counter
flutter: rebuilding widget

Note how the widget stops rebuilding while the app lifecycle is hidden (i.e. the incrementing counter printouts are not followed by rebuilding widget while the app lifecycle state is hidden). I would like to force the app to re-render when the state changes, even when hidden.
Also, it's worth noting that other macOS native apps (e.g. Terminal) refresh without problems while hidden by other windows.

Have you tried this on any other OS? I have tried on linux and it is working as expected.

No, I haven't. I am using macOS, so I need it to work there! Thanks for trying it and providing an extra data point though!

if you are able to modify framework code, modify src/scheduler/binding.dart:SchedulerBinding.handleAppLifecycleStateChanged to enable frames when the app is hidden.
  case AppLifecycleState.resumed:
  case AppLifecycleState.inactive:
    _setFramesEnabledState(true);
  case AppLifecycleState.hidden:
  case AppLifecycleState.paused:
  case AppLifecycleState.detached:
    _setFramesEnabledState(false);

changing to
  case AppLifecycleState.resumed:
  case AppLifecycleState.inactive:
  case AppLifecycleState.hidden:
    _setFramesEnabledState(true);
  case AppLifecycleState.paused:
  case AppLifecycleState.detached:
    _setFramesEnabledState(false);

Otherwise, you may also manually schedule the frames when needed in setState() with SchedulerBinding.instance.scheduleForcedFrame();.
Or keep the frames running forever, even when there is no state changes with
void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
  SchedulerBinding.instance.addPersistentFrameCallback((_) {
    SchedulerBinding.instance.scheduleForcedFrame();
  });
}

(Probably should guard this behaviour to desktop only if the app also support mobile)

Thanks so much! I spent a few hours trying to "fix" it in the Swift glue code, to no avail! I didn't know about SchedulerBinding.

I ended up using SchedulerBinding.instance.scheduleForcedFrame() after setState() when the app is hidden in macOS.
